# Date format to set on column level

Tags: excel, vbscript

Is it possible to set the date format at column level on run time say column `#9` I need to set the date format as `[h]:mm:ss`? I will set the format before transposing an array to that column.

**EDIT**

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("D1").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: `vbscript` or `excel-vba`? Also what have you tried?

Comment: @SiddharthRout VBScript I want!

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: @SiddharthRout `ob.Range.Column(9).format = [h]:mm:ss` . But it is not working there.

Comment: @SiddharthRout too much confusing for VBScript to convert and where i can get such color constant values? Is there any documentations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ob.Range.Column(9).format = [h]:mm:ss

The above has to be written as

```
oXLWs.Columns(9).NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss"
```

Where `oXLWs` is the relevant sheet. For example,

```
Dim oXLApp, oXLWb, oXLWs

Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

oXLApp.Visible = True

Set oXLWb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Add
Set oXLWs = oXLWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

oXLWs.Columns(9).NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss"
```

**FOLLOWUP**

Is this what you want?

```
Dim oXLApp, oXLWb, oXLWs

Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

oXLApp.Visible = True

Set oXLWb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Add
Set oXLWs = oXLWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

With oXLWs.Columns(9)
    .NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss"
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 6 '<~~ Yellow
    .Font.Bold = True '<~~ Bold
    .Font.ColorIndex = 3 '<~~ Red
End With
```

I refer to this old pic for normal colors (picked up from dmcritchie's [site](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm))

[image]

Comment: How to set the font and color for the cells forn the same column,Say I want Yellow as `label` and red as `font color` with `bold` ?

Comment: Record a macro and see what do you get ;)

Comment: It would give me VBA,not vbscript!

Comment: Yup it will but they are very similar and you can simply adapt it for `vbscript`... give it a try and if you are stuck then post the code that you tried and we will take it from there :)

Comment: That's what I was looking for,really appreciated. Your reputation count has the real weight you proved! :-)

Comment: @TukaiRakshit Hi, remember vbscript do not accept the predefined values like `xlSolid` , `xlAutomatic`. You should always resolved their real value in VBA Intermediate windows to values by typing , for exmaple: ?xlSolid  + <ENTER>  to see the value.

This is one tech. of converting VBA into VBS